# Identify battery chemistry

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, battery-chemistry, lifepo4

I have a small project where I would like to use a single 18650 LiFePO4 battery. Problem is that they are somewhat difficult to procure in very small quantities around where I currently live (Japan). The only offers I find are from (in)famous marketplace websites. There I am afraid to just get a cheap Li-ion battery instead, just with the convenient 3.2 V printed on instead of 3.7 V.

So, is there a simple way to distinguish a LiFePO4 cell from a Li-ion cell if the markings are unreliable and a datasheet is not available?

Comment: Go to the person who rebuilds battery packs for power tools, and buy from them. (if that's a thing in japan)

Comment: Measure the open-circuit voltage of the cells.   LiFePO4 are different from LiIon.   Or....  And do it carefully... Poke a nail into a cell.   If it shoots out flames, it's definitely not LiFePO4.   When you pierce one of those, you get a tiny puff of smoke and that's about it.

Comment: @KyleB would the open circuit voltage help if the suspected Li-Ion battery is drained? If I charge it with the LiFePo4 charger, then to voltage should not exceed the range of usual LiFePo4. I like your second suggestion though. Just buy a couple cells at once, create a youtube channel and make a flaming video in front of some beautiful japanese landscape :-D